# Short, pragmatic answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Why was [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfEdd.png) deleted on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506432/ubuntu-wakes-immediately-after-suspend-with-nouveau-on-geforce-gt-525m/506637#506637)? It was a bit short, but remember that some (think SO) of the best answers are short ones. It does answer the OP's question,

> How can I make suspend work?

Of course, it wasn't the best answer; it could have mentioned proprietary drivers or HW-specific packages. But a low-quality answer should be downvoted and commented on, not deleted, right? On the other hand, the [other answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh2HJ.png) is insightful but link-only at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer, while maybe right, needs more details for users that are not familiar with "Software Sources".

As far as the other answer, it wasn't there when your answer was deleted, and it was converted to a comment.

I went ahead and added a comment to your answer, but the original question was closed as off-topic, since it's a bug.